# Select date between SQL. Where date is in format dd/mm/yyyy and is a string

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

In my sql table, I have a string in format 'DD/MM/YYYY'. How can I select a date range? e.g. `table.date BETWEEN '01/01/2019' and '31/10/2019'`? Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the date using the correct data type.  You have to convert the date, which generally affects performance.

In Postgres, you can do:

```
to_date(table.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= '2019-01-01' AND
to_date(table.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < '2020-01-01'
```

In MySQL, this would be:

```
date_format(table.date, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2019-01-01' AND
date_format(table.date, '%d/%m/%Y') < '2020-01-01'
```

In either database, you could also use string manipulation, because you want the full year:

```
table.date LIKE '%/2019'
```